# YouTube Objective-C HTTP POST Request Comment

Tags: objective-c, http, post, youtube, request

I'm trying to add a comment to a YouTube video via my App, but obviously it doesn't work. Then I went to the Api v2 site and saw this:

> POST /feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID/comments HTTP/1.1
>   
> Host: gdata.youtube.com
>   
> Content-Type: application/atom+xml
>   
> Content-Length: CONTENT_LENGTH
>   
> Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN
>   
> GData-Version: 2
>   
> X-GData-Key: key=DEVELOPER_KEY

But it gives me nothing back and it also doesn't post the comment.
So where do i have to send the post request to and what do i have to write in it?

Heres my code so far:

```
SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007'><content>%@</content></entry>", [textField text]];

NSData *postData = [requestString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/FejWBVt7jtk/comments"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/atom+xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", [defaults objectForKey:@"accessToken"]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[request setValue:@"key=DEVELOPER KEY" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-GData-Key"];

[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

NSString *content = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary *dict = [parser objectWithString:content];
NSLog(@"%@", dict);
```

Thank you!

Comment: I hope that isn't your actual YouTube API key.

Comment: it is, but what would you wanna do with it? its just the developer key

Comment: It just seemed like something to keep private. :)

Comment: One issue I can see is that you are trying to parse a XML response using a JSON parser.

Comment: YouTube says I have to give them XML. Itself gives back json.

Comment: The docs say that if you want JSON output you need to append `?alt=json` to the end of the URL. https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_json

Comment: I know, but it doesn't give me anything back, so i dont even need to parse it. I save the output in a string (without jsonparser), but it is null.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what your issue is, but you might have better luck using [Google's Objective-C library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/).